# Jquery não retorna o valor mínimo ao usar Math.min( )

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho a função:

```
$(this.SubOfferGroups).each(function () {
   $(this.AnswerOffersList).each(function () {
      menorValor = Math.min(this.SalePrice.DefaultValue);
   });
});
```

Ao entrar no array `AnswerOffersList`, preciso percorrer e pegar o menor `SalePrice`, que em alguns casos tem dois registros para cada posição no array, porém, o que está vindo é o maior ou último no array.

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 3):

Além do uso incorreto da função `Math.min()`, há um problema de escopo.

A função [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) recebe vários parâmetros e retorna o menor. Ela não tem como verificar a variável que está recebendo o resultado.

E então você precisa declarar a variável `menorValor` fora da função anônima para que ela sobreviva a mais de uma chamada.

Não sei se entendi bem como funciona seu sistema, mas talvez o seguinte código resolva o problema:

```js
$(this.SubOfferGroups).each(function () {
    var menorValor = null;
    $(this.AnswerOffersList).each(function () {
        menorValor = (menorValor == null) ? 
            this.SalePrice.DefaultValue : 
            Math.min(this.SalePrice.DefaultValue, menorValor);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você usar a função [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) para pegar os valores de todos os elementos, e depois pegar o mínimo de todos usando `Math.min`:

```
var valores = $(this.SubOfferGroups).map(function () {
   return $(this.AnswerOffersList).map(function () {
      return this.SalePrice.DefaultValue;
   }).get();
}).get();

var minValor = Math.min.apply(null, valores);
```

**Exemplo:**

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn4vL/)

Answer (score -3):

Resolvi assim:

```
valor = this.SubOfferGroups[0].AnswerOffersList[0].SalePrice.DefaultValue;
$(this.SubOfferGroups).each(function () {

    $(this.AnswerOffersList).each(function () {

        if(valor < this.SalePrice.DefaultValue)
        {
            menorValor = valor;
        }

    });
});
```